# Why am I getting the following error: Symbol’s value as variable is void: org-latex-classes

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

This is a new error, and I haven't really changed anything in my config. The relevant portion is below

```
(use-package org
  :config
  (setf (cdr (assoc 'file org-link-frame-setup)) 'find-file)
  (setq org-directory "~/Documents/Lists/org")
  (setq org-agenda-files '("~/Documents/Lists/org/todo.org"
                           "~/Documents/Lists/org/anniv.org"
                           "~/Documents/Lists/org/events.org"))
  (setq org-log-done 'time) ; Log the time an org task is set to done.
  (setq org-priority-default 67)
  (setq org-agenda-window-setup 'current-window)
  (setq org-agenda-sort-notime-is-late nil)
  (setq org-agenda-span 10)
  (setq org-agenda-start-day "-3d")
  (setq org-export-babel-evaluate nil)
  (setq org-latex-caption-above nil)
  (setq org-preview-latex-process-alist
        '((dvipng :programs
                  ("latex" "dvipng")
                  :description "dvi > png" :message "you need to install the programs: latex and dvipng." :image-input-type "dvi" :image-output-type "png" :image-size-adjust
                  (1.0 . 1.0)
                  :latex-compiler
                  ("latex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f")
                  :image-converter
                  ("dvipng -D %D -T tight -bg Transparent -o %O %f"))
          (dvisvgm :programs
                   ("latex" "dvisvgm")
                   :description "dvi > svg" :message "you need to install the programs: latex and dvisvgm." :image-input-type "dvi" :image-output-type "svg" :image-size-adjust
                   (1.7 . 1.5)
                   :latex-compiler
                   ("latex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f")
                   :image-converter
                   ("dvisvgm %f -n -b min -c %S --currentcolor -o %O")) ; currentcolor is important
          (imagemagick :programs
                       ("latex" "convert")
                       :description "pdf > png" :message "you need to install the programs: latex and imagemagick." :image-input-type "pdf" :image-output-type "png" :image-size-adjust
                       (1.0 . 1.0)
                       :latex-compiler
                       ("pdflatex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f")
                       :image-converter
                       ("convert -density %D -trim -antialias %f -quality 100 %O"))))
  (add-to-list 'org-latex-classes
           `("beamer"
         ,(concat "\\documentclass[presentation]{beamer}\n"
              "[DEFAULT-PACKAGES]"
              "[PACKAGES]"
              "[EXTRA]\n")
         ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}")
         ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}")
         ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection*{%s}")))
  (setq org-latex-listings 'minted
    org-latex-pdf-process '("pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"
                "pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"))
                
  (plist-put org-format-latex-options ':scale 1.1)
  (plist-put org-format-latex-options :foreground nil)
  (plist-put org-format-latex-options :background nil)
  (setq org-latex-packages-alist
           '(("" "tikz" t)
         ("" "tikz-cd" t)
         ("" "minted")))
  (setq org-latex-create-formula-image-program 'dvisvgm)
  (defun my/resize-org-latex-overlays ()
    (cl-loop for o in (car (overlay-lists))
       if (eq (overlay-get o 'org-overlay-type) 'org-latex-overlay)
       do (plist-put (cdr (overlay-get o 'display))
             :scale (expt text-scale-mode-step
                  text-scale-mode-amount))))
  (org-babel-do-load-languages 'org-babel-load-languages '((python . t)
                               (latex . t)))
  :hook
  (org-mode . (lambda () (add-hook 'text-scale-mode-hook #'my/resize-org-latex-overlays nil t)))
  (org-mode . (lambda () (org-indent-mode 1) (visual-line-mode 1))))
```

If I do `counsel-describe-variable` and search for `org-latex-classes` it does not find anything. Has something changed recently?

Comment: What did change? Did you upgrade any packages? Did you upgrade Emacs? Did you change anything at all in your config? Add that information to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The `config` section is run after the `org` package is loaded, but loading the `org` package alone does not define `org-latex-classes`. That is defined in `ox-latex`, so you either need to explicitly require `ox-latex` or you need for it to be loaded during config:

```el
  ...
  (require 'ox-latex) ; <-----------Add this.
  (add-to-list 'org-latex-classes
           `("beamer"
```

Note that `add-to-list` needs to have the variable defined before it is called: it adds an element to the variable's current value, so the variable *has* to have a current value. Note for example, that the same problem does not arise with `org-preview-latex-process-alist` (which is also defined in `ox-latex`) because you are using `setq`, so you either create the variable (if it does not exist already) or you clobber its current value (if it does), so it does not matter whether `ox-latex` is already loaded or not.

As to why it worked before, who knows? You may have added the `add-to-list` recently and have not restarted Emacs since then, or you may have updated Emacs or some package as @db48x suggests in a comment. If you updated, then maybe post your previous version and your current version and we can check if the `require` was present in the earlier version and was deleted in the current version. But without that kind of information, it's difficult to guess.